# Microsoft Teams, get call queue calls queued and agents available Via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to get live stats for a call queues in Microsoft Teams Voice?  Ideally I'd like to see calls queued, agents logged in and agents available.

If so can you guide me to any documentation / provide an example?

Many Thanks

Si

Comment: Could you please have look into this document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/Get-CsCallQueue?view=skype-ps

Are you looking for the same?

Comment: thats a great starting point, many thanks